# Systemd service not restarting on error despite restart=always

Tags: systemd, journalctl

After noticing the error using `journalctl -u raspotify --since=yesterday | grep ERROR`

```
Dec 26 22:50:11 raspberrypi librespot[3024]: [2020-12-26T21:50:11Z ERROR librespot] Could not connect to server: failed to lookup address information: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I restart manually using `systemctl restart raspotify`

What do I need to change in the service in order to restart it automatically on the error

`cat /lib/systemd/system/raspotify.service:`

```
[Unit]
Description=Raspotify
After=network.target

[Service]
User=raspotify
Group=raspotify
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -m 0755 -p /var/cache/raspotify ; /bin/chown raspotify:raspotify /var/cache/raspotify
Environment="DEVICE_NAME=raspotify (%H)"
Environment="BITRATE=160"
Environment="CACHE_ARGS=--disable-audio-cache"
Environment="VOLUME_ARGS=--enable-volume-normalisation --linear-volume --initial-volume=100"
Environment="BACKEND_ARGS=--backend alsa"
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/raspotify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/librespot --name ${DEVICE_NAME} $BACKEND_ARGS --bitrate ${BITRATE} $CACHE_ARGS $VOLUME_ARGS $OPTIONS

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", KERNEL=="wl*", RUN+="/usr/bin/iw dev $name set power_save off"
```

Comment: Did you run `systemctl daemon-reload` after making the change?

Comment: The only other strange things I see is that `PermissionsStartOnly=` is depricated, so `ExecStartPre=` should be `ExecStartPre=+`.  Also, I don't think `;` is supported in the `ExecStartPre=+` line.  It's not bash.  This should be split into two `ExecStartPre=+` lines and they will be run in order.

Comment: @Stewart. Thank you. I didn't change anything